Random DatastoreFailureException for datastore and objectify on appengine
In the last 2-3 months, the frequency of DatastoreFailureException has increased. The issue appears random and is not isolated to any specific entity or API. We are using retries with exponential backoff, but the error persists.
We are using Java 17 and Objectify 5.1.25 on App Engine Standard. Datastore is configured in 'optimistic' concurrency mode.
We opened a support case with the GCP team, and they said this is caused by "concurrent transactions reading the same data" and suggested the following:
"The Datastore team recommends consulting the community for guidance on exploring transaction controls with Objectify, as it is community-supported. If a non-transactional approach is an option, it might be worth considering. Otherwise, you may need to explore pessimistic concurrency control."
These are some of the error logs:

Error occurs after getting parent entity from datastore and then on fetching child entities using live ref.

related code :
 public List<ReferenceFile> getReferences() {
 if (null == references) {
     return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>());
 }
 final List<ReferenceFile> list = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Ref<ReferenceFile> itemRef : references) {
     ReferenceFile item = itemRef.get();
     if (null != item) {
         list.add(item);
     }
 }
 return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

}

Error occurs when getting a list of entities from Datastore.



related code, snippet 1:
 List<Notification> byKeys = notificationDAO.fetchByEntityKey(key);
 notificationList.addAll(byKeys);

snippet 2 for fetchByEntityKey:
 ofy().load().type(clazz).filter(fieldName, fieldValue).list()

Has anyone encountered or resolved similar issues before? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.
